# German keyboard : Ctrl+Alt doesn't work

Tags: raspbian, keyboard

I have a German keyboard on my Raspberry Pi 2B running Raspbian.

Any character that involves "Ctrl+Alt+key" doesn't work (`[]@{}`...).

I've tried all different keyboard layouts in raspi-config but none works.

My keyboard is a LogiLink ID0040.

The content of `/etc/default/keyboard` is :

```
# KEYBOARD CONFIGURATION FILE

# Consult the keyboard(5) manual page.

XKBMODEL="pc105"
XKBLAYOUT="de"
XKBVARIANT="nodeadkeys"
XKBOPTIONS="lv3:ralt_switch,terminate:ctrl_alt_bksp"

BACKSPACE="guess"
```

Thanks in advance for helping.

Comment: Have you tried `AltGr`+`Key`? `AltGr` is the key on the right side of the spacebar.

Comment: Also, could you run `setxkbmap -query` and post the results?

Comment: `AltGr` doesn't work either. The results of `setxkbmap -query` are: `rules: evdev  ;  model: pc105   ;  layout: de   ;  variant: legacy   ;  options: lv3:ralt_alt`

Comment: `sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-layout` could work. I don't know maybe `XKBMODEL="logicd"
 XKBLAYOUT="de"
 XKBVARIANT=""` could be an approach.

Comment: @JoePlatano this doesn't work either :|

Comment: @HugoTrombert, then unfortunately I don't have another idea. There are still products outside that are not working correctly with Linux.

Comment: @JoePlatano OK thanks a lot for helping anyway. Do you know if there's a way to make kind of a system that prints a character when you press a series of keys, anywhere on the raspi. For example, something that enables you to set ''Ctrl+Alt+8" to always mean '[' ?

Comment: I have the same problem. The /etc/default/keyboard file is completely changed to german values like in the example above. Even after a reboot my German Z key will make Y. The strange thing is my German key '-' is working like it should. The english layout would output an '/' when I press '-', but it outputs '-'. So only Z and Y are switched. I already tried raspi-config as root and also sudo dpkg-reconfigure keyboard-layout. Nothing helped. Is this a bug in raspbian or debian?